# React and Material-UI: MuiDialog-root gets stuck after dialog close

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React with MaterialUI, and occasionally when I close the MUI dialog, a div gets stuck on the screen with the class "MuiDialog-root":

`<div class="MuiBackdrop-root" aria-hidden="true" style="opacity: 0; transition: opacity 195ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;">`

I can't seem to make it dissapear without refreshing the page, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue. You are most likely using the TransitionComponent property of the Dialog component. You need to move the transition function creation to outside of the component you are using it in.

```
const DialogTransition = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (<Slide ... />));

export default function MyDialog(...) {
    return (
        <Dialog TransitionComponent={DialogTransition} ...>
        ...
    );
}
```

source: [github issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9116)